# need to change one element in xml based on a logic

Tags: xml, xslt

i have a requirement to change the value in one element based on a logic
i want to change the percentage 0.07 with the above value 0.045

i used template match to get it but it is not going through the template

```
 <peci:Benefits_Earnings_and_Deductions>
            <peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>Pension Aegon
                (Uk)</peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>
            <peci:External_Payroll_Code>REGPEN</peci:External_Payroll_Code>
            <peci:Earning_or_Deduction>D</peci:Earning_or_Deduction>
            <peci:Amount>0</peci:Amount>
            <peci:Percentage>0.045</peci:Percentage>
            <peci:Frequency>Monthly</peci:Frequency>
            <peci:Currency>GBP</peci:Currency>

        </peci:Benefits_Earnings_and_Deductions>

        <peci:Benefits_Earnings_and_Deductions>
            <peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>Pension Aegon ER
                (Uk)</peci:External_Payroll_Code_Name>
            <peci:External_Payroll_Code>REGPENER</peci:External_Payroll_Code>
            <peci:Earning_or_Deduction>D</peci:Earning_or_Deduction>
            <peci:Amount>0</peci:Amount>
            <peci:Percentage>0.07</peci:Percentage>
            <peci:Frequency>Monthly</peci:Frequency>
            <peci:Currency>GBP</peci:Currency>
        </peci:Benefits_Earnings_and_Deductions>
```

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add the XSLT code that you have tried?

Comment: Also, your XML contains a namespace prefix; `peci:`, so it should really contain a namespace declaration for that in the form of `xlmns:peci="..."`. You should show that in your XML too, especially because one reason your template is not matching may be because you are not accounting for the namespace in your XSLT. Thanks!

Comment: i used the namespace also

Comment: @AniketV the requirement is percentage 0.07 should be replaced with the above value 0.045

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the XSLT you have tried, so we can explain why it is not working as expected and propose the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Please post the root of your XML which usually contains namespace definitions. Right now, this fragment is not a well-formed XML.